# If new param added in store procedure and not updaing the pass param in ado.net command object how to remove this error from store procedure

Tags: c#, ado.net

If new param added in store procedure and not updaing the pass param in ado.net command object how to remove this error from store procedure : Parameter count does not match Parameter Value count

Comment: make the new  parameter as `optional` , if it is not necessary.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?